# system commant wont work as in shell when calling a python comman on Ubuntu from R

Tags: python, r, shell

I'm trying to invoke within `R` a system command that invokes a call to a python script (that includes an import to pandas)  as following:

```
getwd()
[1] "/home/production"
> system("python In_tag_main_model/python_scripts/connect_to_couchbase.py")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "In_tag_main_model/python_scripts/connect_to_couchbase.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Within `connect_to_couchbase.py` i'm calling pandas, which isn't recognized, though when i'm running  this exact command from my machines shell:

```
production@va-rsrv01:~$ python In_tag_main_model/python_scripts/connect_to_couchbase.py
production@va-rsrv01:~$
```

It works great,any ides why `system` isn't working for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you completely sure that the `python` used when you call via R is the same as the one you use in the terminal? Note that the `PATH` variable may be different. Try to run from R the command `which python`

Comment: It isnt! how can i set system from '/usr/bin/python' to '/anaconda2/bin/python'?

Comment: The simplest way is to just use the complete path, so `/anaconda2/bin/python In_tag_main_model/...`.  I'm not an R user but the page for the [`system`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) function says that newer programs should use [`system2`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html) and I can see that this second function has an `env` parameter in which you could set the `PATH` so that the `/anaconda2/bin` directory is search for executables.

Comment: i fixed it through Sys.setenv(PATH="/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games")
system("python In_tag_main_model/python_scripts/connect_to_couchbase.py")

Comment: thanks, please post it as an answer, ill give you the credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the R `system` function is executing a different python executable. You have three options to specify which executable you want:

- You the absolute path:

  ```
  system("/anaconda2/bin/python In_tag_main_model/python_scripts/connect_to_couchbase.py")
  ```
- Set the `PATH` variable for your process via [`Sys.setenv`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.setenv.html) (as you have done):

  ```
  Sys.setenv(PATH="/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bi‌​n:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games")
  system("python In_tag_main_model/python_scripts/connect_to_couchbase.py")
  ```
- Use the newer [`system2`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html) function which provides an `env` argument that can be used to modify the environmental variables for the subprocess:

  ```
  system2("python",
          args="In_tag_main_model/python_scripts/connect_to_couchbase.py",
          env="PATH=/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bi‌​n:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games")
  ```

  Note that `system2` has a different calling convention than `system`.